# Are the values for all technical indicators obtained from an asset's price?

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis, market-data, indicators

There are several types of technical indicators, for example, trend, momentum, volatility & volume.

My question is, are the values for ***all*** indicators obtained from an asset's price? If not, what other data could be used to obtain the values for these indicators?

I understand that my question might come of as broad but I'm trying to determine if ***all*** indicators use the same data to obtain the values for their charts/indicators.

Answer (score 1):

Volume is not a technical indicator.  It is a datapoint as are the open, high, low, close, change from yesterday.

Technical indicators are derivatives of price and/or volume (rate of change, stochastics, RSI, MACD, money flow, volatility, etc.).  These are formula based.

Chart patterns are also derivatives but they are not necessarily formula based (support and resistance, trendlines, flags, pennants, Head & Shoulders, etc.).